# Slow taking screenshots with prt sc key

Tags: 16.04, gnome-screenshot

Just after I installed Ubuntu, taking screenshots using <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> worked perfectly.

But now (about one or two weeks after installation), It takes at least 20 seconds to take just one screenshot using <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>.

However, when I open gnome-screenshot and click <kbd>Take Screenshot</kbd>, it works without any delay.

Comment: I'm noticing the same, did you ever get it fixed?